# Vue variable not accessible in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I have defined a variable called `$shopifyClient` within `Vue` which is not accessible in `Vuex`. How do i make thi variable accessible?

```
Vue.$shopifyClient.addLineItems('1234', lineItems).then((checkout) => {
    console.log(checkout.lineItems)
})
```

returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLineItems' of undefined`, so i would assume it cannot retrieve `$shopifyClient`.

## main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.prototype.$shopifyClient = new Client(
  new Config({
    domain: 'some-page.myshopify.com',
    storefrontAccessToken: '123456'
  })
)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

## store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    lineItems: { }
  },
  actions: {
    addToCart ({ commit, state }) {
      var lineItems = [{variantId: '12345==', quantity: 2}]
      Vue.$shopifyClient.addLineItems('1234', lineItems).then((checkout) => {
        console.log(checkout.lineItems)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: As per my knowledge, you cannot access like that. What you want to achieve? You want to store all the fetched lineItems to store in vuex store?

Comment: The action basically sends a post to shopify to add the item to the checkout instance and returns the new checkout object, which contains the new content. The content is then added to the store.

Comment: I am not sure but you can try storing `$shopifyClient` directly in vuex store variables and then use it? This way you can access it from any vue components and also in store actions.

Comment: Hmm, i did not really think of that, but that could be a way to go, but i will be using it in other components as well, so i may end up having two different objects laying around, one in vuex and in vue's global scope.

Comment: As I said earlier, you can access it in other components if you have declared it in vuex store.

Comment: Can you make a small example showing how i get the variable `shopifyClient` in other components from vuex store, that would shed some light on the confusion..

Comment: check [this](https://pastebin.com/H93pfqYg). It may help you.

Comment: Works perfectly.. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to know. I will add it as an answer. Accept it if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `$shopifyClient` in `Vuex` store as shown below:

```
//Store.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    lineItems: { },
    $shopifyClient: new Client(
      new Config({
        domain: 'some-page.myshopify.com',
        storefrontAccessToken: '123456'
     })
)
  },
  actions: {
    addToCart ({ commit, state }) {
      var lineItems = [{variantId: '12345==', quantity: 2}]
      state.$shopifyClient.addLineItems('1234', lineItems).then((checkout)     => {
        console.log(checkout.lineItems)
      })
    }
  }
})


// vue component
//you can access it like below

this.$root.$store.state.$shopifyClient;
```